# Why is my Google Cast device not visible to the browser extension but visible to an iPhone iOS sender?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

I'm experiencing problems with Google Cast and the Google Chrome sender application that I have developed. In some circumstances the device will not show up in the Google Cast extension unless a session is started by another sender type i.e. an iPhone sender. Even then it is not possible to cast anything to it, it just shows up as being present on the network.

This is not always the case though. When I developed the Chrome sender application the device would sometimes disappear from the list in the extension but when I restarted the browser it showed up again. But a lot of our customers are experiencing that they never see the device listed.

Anyone have an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a PEBCAK problem. I was working against a receiver which required devices to be whitelisted when I thought I wasn't.